# Get autocorrection from UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, autocorrect

How can I get the word suggested by the autocorrect mechanism when a user is typing into a `UITextField`?

Comment: I need this too. I disable Done button whenever the text being edited matches the original text in a `UITextField`. Problem is, when the autocorrection suggests "Text" whereas the user has typed "text" and the original was "text", the Done button would remain disabled where it should not. This is because, "Text" would be accepted on tapping Done, if the button were enabled, which is the expected behavior. So, I need to know the suggestion, and whether it's accepted or rejected by default, i.e., whether the suggestion is in a white or black background respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  There is no public API to find out what suggestion is being offered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UITextChecker` class :
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`UITextInputTraits`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextAutocorrectionType), it has a property `autocorrectionType`

```
typedef enum {
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes,
} UITextAutocorrectionType;
```

so you can try `yourTextfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;`